# Unable to start call Activity while device is lock

Tags: android, android-activity, call

I'm trying to open the activity on lock screen when I receive the notification form twilio. But I'm facing issue as it called onDestroy method when screen is locked on call receiving and it doesn't open the required activity.
I tried many solution but none of them worked.
I also tried following code to open activity on Lock screen but it doesn't work.

```
Window window=getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: try wake lock screen in android to wake up the screen

Comment: thanks for your interest! i already tried wake lock screen to wake up screen but its not working for me